# How to model 1 to 0..* aggregation in UML

Tags: c++, uml, enterprise-architect

I would like to model a `Hal_device_factory` class with container, that collects pointers to interfaces of type `IHal_subfactory`.

I made such class diagram in Enterprise Architect:

[image]

Then I generated source code for this diagram, this is what i've got:

```
std::set<IHal_subfactory>  *m_IHal_subfactory;
```

However I expected something like that :

```
std::set<IHal_subfactory*>  m_IHal_subfactory;
```

So my question is what I've done wrong ? 
Model is wrong or what ?

Comment: Is it now more clear ?

Answer (score 3):

I think, your model is correct.

If you want to have an **instance** of your `set` instead of a **pointer** to it:

you should set your Aggregation containment to `Value` instead of `Reference`:

In your Aggregation Relationship -> go to **Properties** -> **Role(s)** -> in **Source** section -> in the list at **Advanced** section -> set **Containment** to `Value`.

Comment: This is it.. Thank you !